# I do not want Notification Manager to open an activity

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I do not want Notification Manager (Status bar) to open an activity. Instead when a notification is clicked, it is just cancelled, and nothing must happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"A New Message!",System.currentTimeMillis());

notification.defaults=Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE+Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, null);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(AndroidNotifications.this, title,message, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Rather than passing class in intent just pass null or use intent() default constructor instead .
if helps appreciate.

Comment: Or try to use this PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,null, 0);

Answer (score 4):

When you create the `PendingIntent` pass an empty Intent `new Intent()`

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0)
```

and set the FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL Flag for the notification

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty activity that calls `finish()` from `onCreate()` and set it in the `PendingIntent`. An empty (null) one is not allowed, so that is your best bet, AFAIK.